# Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner: chapter 3 ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop

So in this book chapter 3 subsection "Creating Intentional Infinite Loops" author gives this example:

```
# Finicky Counter
# Demonstrates the break and continue statements
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
# end loop if count greater than 10
if count > 10:
    break
# skip 5
if count == 5:
    continue
print(count)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

But it doesn't work. It only spits out break-outside-loop and continue-not-properly-in-loop errors. From what I've read break/continue can't be used to break out of an if - it can only break out of loops, and that I should use `sys.exit()` or `return`. The question arises, what the author meant, and why he made this -basic?- mistake? Or maybe it isn't a mistake and I'm missing something.

Could you help me grasp this concept of break/continue function with fairly similar and simple example? :)

Comment: your indentations are not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentations matter in python. So it must be,

```
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    # end loop if count greater than 10
    if count > 10:
        break
    # skip 5
    if count == 5:
        continue
print(count)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuz you miss-indented it, so do:

```
# Finicky Counter
# Demonstrates the break and continue statements
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    # end loop if count greater than 10
    if count > 10:
        break
    # skip 5
    if count == 5:
        continue
print(count)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

So the lines:

```
# end loop if count greater than 10
if count > 10:
    break
# skip 5
if count == 5:
    continue
```

Got all a extra tab, so it becomes:

```
    # end loop if count greater than 10
    if count > 10:
        break
    # skip 5
    if count == 5:
        continue
```

Note: even if you remove `break` and `continue`, there will be still a problem, it will be an infinite loop.